# View in a module not displaying image but it will display text

Tags: wpf, image, mef

I am using MEF, Prism and WPF. I have a simple module (for now, I'll do more with it when I get past this roadblock) that displays a single image sourced as static resource in that module. Here is the xaml for the view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SplashScreenModule.SplashView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="960" Width="1180">
    <Grid>
        <Label>
            <Image Source="Images/My Image.png"/>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
```

The image shows up in the designer but when I run the code the window is blank. If I replace the image with simple text the text is display as expected.

```
<Label>
    This shows up in the window.
</Label>
```

I've spent the last 3 hours trying to figure this out and am stumped. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Could you specify why you want to create an explicit `BitmapSource` object and reference it via `StaticResource` instead of just using '<Image Source="Images/My Image.png" />`? Is that not an option?

Comment: I didn't. This was actually a hold over from some earlier code I had written. However, I made that change and it had no effect. I updated the original question to reflect the simpler example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that there is a difference on how ressources are managed at DesignTime and at RunTime. At DesignTime there is no compilation required, thus it is able to display a ressource even if it is not include in the project.

At runtime this is normally possible, but it is better to include the ressources in your project (ie create a folder Images in your solution, and add the "My Image.png" in this folder), to be sure of the location of your ressource compared to your exe.

If you do it and the image still doesn't show up, try to remove the label and execute again.
By doing this it works fine for me. As soon as the image show up, you can add back the label.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working for me:

```
<Window x:Class="LabelImage.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label>
            <Image Source="Images/visual studio.png" />
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I structured my solution like you did: I have the picture inside a folder named Images. The MainWindow is located directly under the project node (it's not in any subdirectory).

[image]

Make sure that the Build Action for your image is set to resource, otherwise it won't work with the WPF Resource Finding System (which internally uses PACK-Uris: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx)

I use .NET 4.5 with VS 2013. If you have any further questions, please feel free to ask.

**Update after Bill's comment**:

That's a whole different thing when your resource resides within another assembly. The syntax for referencing the image should be like this:

```
<Image Source="/ClassLibraryForResources;component/Images/visual studio.png" />
```

where you do the following steps:

1. Begin with a slash "/"
2. Specify the name of the assembly that holds your resource (this can also be a strong assembly name)
3. Continue with ";component/"
4. End with the path of the image (or other resource)
   (Please note that you have to omit the quotation marks).

The solution that I used is structured like this:

[image]

This should resemble what you have described. Again: it's all about the PACK URIs that WPF uses (see link above).

Comment: This also works for me, but only if the embedded resource is in the executable assembly. If I build it as a DLL and load it as a module I do not see the image. I do see literal (text) contents of a label but not images loaded from resources.

Comment: I appreciate the help so far, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Is the setup like the one I depicted above? Can you supply a test project that shows your problem? Does the code I presented above work for you?

Comment: Yes. I got it to work late last night. The final problem was that I had to copy the module's DLL to the applications bin\debug folder. Since this is a modular system the module DLL is not referred to by the application. It is discovered at run time. However, it will not load images from the module's assembly from there. One other wrinkle I haven't figured out yet is that the control's XAML can not be in a folder (Views) it can't find the image. Bottom line is that it is working now. 

Now off to conquer custom Routed Events!